# Rocket propulsion energy efficiency

Tags: rocket-science, propulsion, optimization

What ratio of final to initial mass of a rocket to achieves the highest energy efficiency - the highest ratio of final mass kinetic energy to chemical energy expended? And more generally the relation of efficiency to mass ratio. This is a bit hypothetical because we are not usually interested in efficiency in this sense, but the answer is curious none the less.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this will be evaluated in the frame where the ship starts at rest?  Since you want the ratio of chemical energy expended, then we assume the ship always has 1 unit of fuel.  If you take $r$ as the ratio of final to initial mass, then $m_f$ is just $r^{-1}$ and $m_0$ is $r^{-1} - 1$.

Then the final kinetic energy of the ship is (ignoring constants):
$$E \propto m_f \space (\Delta v)^2$$
$$E \propto (r^{-1} - 1) \left ( \ln{\frac{r^{-1}}{r^{-1} - 1}}\right )^2$$

That derivative is a bit more than I want to deal with right now, but a calculator says it has a maximum near $r=0.7968$

Comment: I don't follow this because the mass ratio calculated from the expressions is not $r$. In any case im assuming something more usual - the energy expended is proportional to the mass lost $(m_0 - m_f)$, ie for a given chemical propellant, so   
$$
E_{kin}/E_{chem} \propto m_f (\ln{m_0 / m_f})^2 / (m_0 - m_f) = (\ln{r^{-1}})^2 / (r^{-1} - 1)
$$

I get max at $r \propto .25, r^{-1 }\propto 5.0$

Comment: Apologies.  I flipped $r$ and it is the fuel fraction instead of final to initial.  So the fraction you asked for is (1 - r) or 0.2032.